# Get a warning in Visual Studio that it can't find css files in defined locations

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

This is a ReSharper issue (if I disable ReSharper, the problem goes away). I get a warning in the IDE that it cannot find the following css files:

1. Ones in _content
2. Ones in _framework
3. The built at render time {APPLICATION].styles.css

Is there a way to turn off the warning for these specific cases? I do want it on for finding legit errors.

[image]

Comment: What version of ReSharper / Visual Studio are you using? You can disable ReSharper to see if it that is causing the warnings.

Comment: @PiersMyers Good idea - disabled ReSharper and the warning went away. So ReSharper issue.